# Is there a specific name for this kind of water dispenser?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, image-identification

I see these water jars in many food service areas (hotels, company cafeteria, etc).  I'm wondering if there is a specific name for them.  "Water dispenser" seems too *unspecific*.  I wonder if they original from a certain style or region, which *does* have a name?

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: When it's designed for coffee it's a [coffee urn](https://www.google.com/images?q=coffee+urn). I haven't really heard "water urn," but the google image search for "[glass water urn](https://www.google.com/images?q=glass+water+urn)" shows one of your example photos.

Comment: I usually see these types of jars/urns/whatchamacallems used for iced tea or lemonade, not water. No clue what they're called, though.

Comment: *Spigot jug* also is in common use ([1](http://www.treehugger.com/kitchen-design/recycled-diamond-spigot-jug.html),[2](http://www.polyvore.com/three-tier_spigot_jug_at_brylanehome.com/thing?id=15081601),[3](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1006&bih=595&q=tea+jug&oq=tea+jug&gs_l=img.3..0j0i5l9.1268.2932.0.3342.7.7.0.0.0.0.241.1162.0j6j1.7.0....0...1ac.1.30.img..1.6.970._6pN6FLjOag#hl=en&q=+spigot+jug&tbm=isch))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Google image searched "glass water jar with spigot", and then clicked through to view page for about 15 selected images.

Results, in order of commonality:

- Beverage dispenser
- Infuser jar  (Indicating that there would be cut up fruit to flavour the water)
- Spigot jar

Comment: yes, well, that's google for you

Comment: despite my previous swipe, it seems that this style of jar is most-often used for serving water-infusions.   Infuser Jar may be 'correct' even when only pure water is being served.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost a samovar, but I think the word is usually reserved for a more specific construction.

Answer (score 1):

I know they are marketed in the US as an "Italian Beverage Jar".  Sangria comes to mind.  But an Italian friend says he has never encountered such a jar in Italy.

Comment: Sangria is Spanish in [origin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangria), not Italian.

Answer (score 1):

Having been in the market for one of these recently, I struggled with finding the correct keyword terms for search engine results. It appears that they are marketed variously as “beverage jars,” “beverage dispensers,” “water dispensers” “spigoted jars,” et al. ...The one constant that I *did* see, however, was the Spanish word “Vitrolero” ...and typing *that* word into amazon and google yielded the best results I was able to find.[image]

Comment: That word is used in Mexico,I believe.

Answer (score 0):

*jar, infusion jar, spigot jar, beverage dispenser, glass urn, vodka dispenser*

… from Google 'Search by Image'.

Answer (score 0):

Cistern is the traditional name for a spigoted vessel.  Proper names like this are being lost in the dumbing of society.  Retailers call it beverage dispenser since people are less educated and poorly read.  Sad.

Comment: Cistern is generally a term used for ground-based water tanks.  Wikipedia, no authority of completeness, [regardless reinforces the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cistern).

Comment: The history of [*cistern*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cistern&allowed_in_frame=0), all the way back through Latin, puts the container **underground**. Before that, *kiste* is a general Greek term for *container* that develops eventually in to English [*chest*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chest&allowed_in_frame=0). And before that it was PIE *kista*, meaning *woven container*. I haven't found a dictionary that denotes a small container with a spigot as a *cistern*, but perhaps you are aware of some remote dialectical anomaly that escapes my notice.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.99993/2015.99993.The-Oxford-English-Dictionary-Vol-2c#page/n447/mode/2up Applied to *various large vessels* for *water or liquor*. There are references to cisterns being used at banquets, for holding either water or liquor, as the case may be.

Comment: Not sure what the contemptuous social commentary adds here…

Answer (score 0):

The word is kilner, or kilner jar.  Try googling kilner cocktail dispenser.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our Q&A format prefers answers where the answerer has done the googling, and included the link and relevant excerpts from the link.

Comment: This is a great answer. I hope you will provide some background information and cite some references to support it.

Comment: When I google that, I see jars with hinged lids and rubber seals, with no spigots.  The dispensing spigot is a critical element in a dispensing container of the sizes shown.  Thanks for the answer, though

Comment: https://www.bar-equipment.com/en/vintage-glasses/450-vintage-kilner-dispenser-5-lt.html The brand name, "Kilner" is on this big vintage jar which has a spigot.

Comment: What's more, the Wikipedia kilner jar is a screw top nothing like what you get in google images. Google images show what Wikipedia calls a flip top.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently indicated that some European communities call this a "hostess beverage dispenser" or just a "hostess".  The latter seems most colloquial, but also more toward an actual specific name, as compared with a word/phrase that describes its utility.

Regardless, the term "hostess beverage dispenser" focuses on the way that it is used: by someone hosting an event (or venue) for guests.